# Pandas json_normalize with nested JSON

Tags: json, pandas, normalize

I have tried many alternatives and the better result was with this statement:

```
json_normalize(a['solution'][0]['tour'])
```

I can see just one block of tours at a time. **vehicle_id 0** information and I need them all together. Thank you.

The JSON is:

```
{
    "total_clusters": 6,
    "solution": [
        {
            "vehicles_id": "0",
            "vehicles_location": {
                "lat": "",
                "lng": ""
            },
            "tour": [
                {
                    "shipping_id": "4a4b0750-63a7-11ea-8955-43fcb2cd860a",
                    "type": "dropoff",
                    "location_id": "797",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "lat": "-34.545736",
                        "lng": "-58.488340"
                    },
                    "cluster": 0
                },
                {
                    "shipping_id": "75e5a2c0-6314-11ea-b657-ddd473c629a3",
                    "type": "dropoff",
                    "location_id": "114",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "lat": "-34.568707",
                        "lng": "-58.452963"
                    },
                    "cluster": 0                 
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "vehicles_id": "1",
            "vehicles_location": {
                "lat": "",
                "lng": ""
            },
            "tour": [
                {
                    "shipping_id": "c83ac7c0-51c4-11ea-9aef-973de7785221",
                    "type": "pickup",
                    "location_id": "687",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "lat": "-34.592824",
                        "lng": "-58.375457"
                    },
                    "cluster": 1
                },
                {
                    "shipping_id": "b5a295c0-51c4-11ea-b36d-651ee769ca89",
                    "type": "pickup",
                    "location_id": "687",
                    "coordinates": {
                        "lat": "-34.592824",
                        "lng": "-58.375457"
                    },
                    "cluster": 1            
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Desired Output
[image]

Comment: Please edit your json as there are brackets missing.

Comment: in addition to rpanai's comment, kindly post ur expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the `record_path` parameter to `json_normalize`.

From the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html):

> **record_path** : str or list of str, default None
>
> Path in each object to list of records. If not passed, data will be assumed to be an array of records.

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

raw_json_data = """{contents_of_your_json_here}"""
json_data = json.loads(raw_json_data)

df = pd.json_normalize(json_data, ["solution", "tour"])
```

Result:
[image]